# Circles of radius $1, 2, 3, ..., n$ all touch a middle circle. How to make the middle circle as small as possible?

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, discrete-geometry

Non-overlapping circles of radius $1, 2, 3, ..., n$ are all externally tangent to a middle circle.

> How should we arrange the surrounding circles, in order to minimize the middle circle's radius $R$?

Take $n=10$ for example.

[image]

On the left, going anticlockwise the radii are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$, and $R\approx 10.77$.
On the right, going anticlockwise the radii are $10, 2, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5, 1, 8, 3$ and $R\approx 9.98$.
How should the circles be arranged to minimize $R$?

Here is a [desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gbtftg0llp?lang=zh-CN) where you can try different arrangements for the case $n=10$.

### **My attempt**

For general $n$, call the radii of the surrounding circles going anti-clockwise, $r_1, r_2, r_3, ..., r_n$.

Draw line segments from the centre of the middle circle to the centre of each surrounding circle. So we have $n$ angles at the centre of the middle circle. Each of these angles can be expressed in terms of $R, r_k, r_{k+1}$, using the [law of cosines](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofCosines.html). The sum of the $n$ angles is $2π$. So we have:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arccos{\left(\frac{(R+r_k)^2+(R+r_{k+1})^2-(r_k+r_{k+1})^2}{2(R+r_k)(R+r_{k+1})}\right)}=2\pi \text{ (where }r_{n+1}=r_1)$$

This simplifies to:

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arccos{\left(1-\frac{2r_k r_{k+1}}{(R+r_k)(R+r_{k+1})}\right)}=2\pi$$

We want to assign each $r$ a unique value among $1, 2, 3, ..., n$ so that $R$ is minimized. But how? Is there a general pattern?

### Conjectured answer

I think the following general procedure will make the middle circle as small as possible. Take $n=10$ for example. We ignore the $1$ at first; it will be placed last. First put down the numbers $10, 9, 8, 7, 6$ in pyramid-fashion, from top to down and from left to right, like the red numbers below. Then put down the numbers $2, 3, 4, 5$ in pyramid-fashion also, but between the previous rows, like the blue numbers below.

[image]

This gives the order of radii going around the circle: $7, 4, 9, 2, 10, 3, 8, 5, 6$. Then put the circle with radius $1$ anywhere you like, as long as it fits without disturbing other circles.

For larger values of $n$, there may be multiple small circles that can fit between other circles without disturbing them. Put those last.

Intuitively, this procedure minimizes the tendency of the large surrounding circles to take up space around the middle circle. You can see this in the diagrams above with $n=10$, looking specifically at the two largest surrounding circles in each case.

Anyway, it's just a conjecture for now. Notice that this conjecture implies that, for $n=10$, the arrangement I showed above on the right, yields the minimum radius of the middle circle. I don't think the middle circle can be any smaller.

Comment: First thing tthat comes to my mind is to take the derivative with respect to $R$ and see the condition for it to vanish.

Comment: @Dog_69 That approach is very difficult due to the $\sum$, I think.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same

Comment: @Dan Yes, absolutely. Actually, I think there's no point trying that. For small numbers (say, $n=7,8,9,10$) one might solve the equation numerically for all the possible combinations of $r_k$. Perhaps that gives a clue on how the $r_k$ must be arranged for general $n$.

Comment: The problem with the current sum of $\arccos$ is that you can have gaps between circles. For example, in the arrangement on the right, there would have to be some wiggle room for the circle of radius $1$ between the circles of radius $5$ and $8$ (i.e. it can't be tangent to both of those and the middle circle), and numerically solving for $R$ using the sum of $\arccos$ yields $\approx 9.90$, different from the $\approx 9.98$ that it would actually be.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Good point. I took this point into account in my desmos graph, but forgot to mention this in my question. We should ignore the smallest few circles, because they will each fit between some two other circles that touch each other. How many circles should be ignored, depends on $n$, with an upper limit of $n/4$ (based on [Descartes' Circle Theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/descartes-theorem/)).

Comment: It seems the right drawing the small circle may be removed without impacting the result.

Comment: I wrote a program that loops over all permutations of 2...10 (excluding the circle of radius 1), and finds an $R$ that solves the equation that you wrote (the sum of the arc-cosines). It confirmed that the optimal permutation is the one that you conjectured: 2, 9, 4, 7, 6, 5, 8, 3, 10, where the radius of the inner circle is ~9.979907. I had to exclude the circle of radius $1$ from the sum of course.